# ValueError at /posts/create/15/: Cannot assign "<Group: Group 2>": "Post.group" must be a "Group" instance

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I am writing the create method for a post, which belongs to a group and a user. I keep getting this error, although this is how it's done in the documentation and every other source i've looked at. here are the relevant files:

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, Group


class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    body = models.TextField()
    likes_total = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField()
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


def __str__(self):
    return self.name

def summary(self):
    # return the 1st 100 chars
    return self.body[:100]

def pub_date_pretty(self):
    # strftime is how to break down time
    return self.pub_date.strftime('%b %e %Y')
```

posts.urls.py

```
from . import views
from django.urls import path


app_name = 'posts'

urlpatterns = [
    path('create/<int:group_id>/', views.create, name='create'),
]
```

posts.views.py

```
def create(request, group_id):
    group = get_object_or_404(Group, pk= group_id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.POST['body']:
            post = Post()
            post.title = request.POST['title']
            post.body = request.POST['body']
            post.pub_date = timezone.datetime.now()
            post.author = request.user
            post.group = group
            post.save()
            return redirect('/groups/' + str(group_id))

        else:
            return render(request, 'groups/detail.html', {'group':group})

    else:
        return render(request, 'groups/detail.html', {'group':group})
```

the error is thrown when I am saving the group to the post (post.group = group), although this the method that ive learned. Hope someone can figure this out. thanks!!

Comment: Please show us how you are importing `Group` in `views.py`?

Comment: from groups.models import Group

Comment: change it to `from django.contrib.auth.models import Group`

Comment: ok, now the problem is that it's not able to grab the group object, its giving a 404 error, although the object clearly exists and it'd id is in the url. any thoughts?

Answer (score 4):

You seem to have mixed up two different `Group` models. In your model you have:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, Group
```

and in your view you have:

```
from groups.models import Group
```

These are completely different classes, which is why you get an error telling you that you can't assign `groups.models.Group` to what should be a `auth.models.Group`.

I'm not sure which you intend it to be, but you need to use the same class in both places.

Comment: ok i've changed the import statement to "from django.contrib.auth.models import  Group" .  now the problem is that it's not able to grab the group object, its giving a 404 error, although the object clearly exists and it'd id is in the url. any thoughts?

Comment: There's not enough information to help you - it must not exist if the query returns no objects. The fact that the ID is in the URL doesn't mean it exists. Where is the ID coming from?