# IntegrityError at /posts/create/18/: Key (group_id)=(18) is not present in table "auth_group"

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

getting this error when running the following code when trying to create a post, which belongs to a group and a user:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from groups.models import Group
from .models import Post
from django.utils import timezone


def create(request, group_id):
    group = get_object_or_404(Group, pk= group_id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.POST['body'] and request.POST['body']:
            post = Post()
            post.title = request.POST['title']
            post.body = request.POST['body']
            post.pub_date = timezone.datetime.now()
            post.author = request.user
            post.group = group
            post.save()
            return redirect('/groups/' + str(group_id))

        else:
            return render(request, 'groups/detail.html', {'group':group})

    else:
        return render(request, 'groups/detail.html', {'group':group})
```

TO clarify, Groups is a model I created, not the default Django model, which is why i imported it from groups.models.

this is what my model for a Post looks like:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from groups.models import Group


class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    body = models.TextField()
    likes_total = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField()
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def summary(self):
        # return the 1st 100 chars
        return self.body[:100]

    def pub_date_pretty(self):
        # strftime is how to break down time
        return self.pub_date.strftime('%b %e %Y')
```

I dont get why the error is looking for the group in the auth_group table, when I imported it from my groups.models file! any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: change the name of your table `Group`

Answer (score 1):

In your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50042927/valueerror-at-posts-create-15-cannot-assign-group-group-2-post-group), `Post.group` pointed to the `auth.Group` model. Now that you have changed it to point to `groups.Group`, you have to create and run migrations to update your database.

Comment: He will still get the issue, @Nader needs to delete that field, run migrations, and re-add it back. That will clear that foreign Key in db

Comment: @Lemayzeur The `makemigrations` command can handle the model changing in the foreign key, although you may get integrity errors when you run migrate. If you delete the foreign key then recreate it, then you'll avoid any integrity errors when migrating, but you'll lose any existing data which might not be acceptable.

Comment: It worked! didnt need the data, so deleting the data in the db was alright. thanks yall